# How to minimize step size in each iteration when using Gradient Descent Method (R)?

Tags: r, optimization, computer-science

I wrote a R code to find the minimum of a function using Gradient Descent Method below:

```
gradient.method <- function(f, grad, init, unit.fac=TRUE, interval=c(-7,10), tol=1e-11, max.iter = 35)
{
newpair <- init
oldpair <- newpair - 1
iter <- 0
while(iter < max.iter & sqrt(sum((newpair - oldpair)^2)) > tol){
iter <- iter + 1
oldpair <- newpair

#Set up the unit vector u
newstep <- if(unit.fac) grad(x)(oldpair)/sqrt(sum(grad(x)(oldpair)**2)) 

#Get minimum of f(x_0 - step_size*grad(x_0))
value <- function(step_size) oldpair - step_size*newstep 
min <- optimize(f(x)(value(step_size)),interval)

#Get new pair of vector x
newpair <- oldpair - min*newstep

}
list(minimum = newpair, value = f(x)(newpair), nsteps = iter)
}
```

The functions for f and grad are as follows:

```
f1 <- function(x){
  n<-length(x)
    function(theta){
    -logLike<- 0.5*n*log(theta[2])-(1/(2*theta[2]))*sum((x-theta[1])**2)
    }
}


g1 <- function(x){
  n <- length(x)
  function(theta){
  grd1 <- -sum((x - theta[1])*theta[2])
  grd2 <- n/(theta[2]) - 0.5*sum(x - theta[1])
  }
}
```

However, I kept getting an error regarding one of my variables: step_size when testing the code. How should I correct the problem? Thanks.

```
res<-gradient.method(f=f1, grad=g1, init=c(100,100), max.iter=100)
Error in value(step_size) : object 'step_size' not found
```

Comment: What does this error you get *means* for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is quite clear, you are trying to use variable `step_size` which has not been defined anywhere. The problem stems from the fact that you aren't using `optimize` function properly, you should give it the name of your function which is minimized with regards to it's first argument. From help page of `optimize` (use `?optimize`):

> f
>
> the function to be optimized. The function is either minimized or
>   maximized over its first argument depending on the value of maximum.

So you should be using `optimize` like this:

```
value <- function(step_size) oldpair - step_size*newstep 
fn<-function(step_size) f(x)(value(step_size))
min <- optimize(fn,interval)
```

Also the variable `x` is not defined anywhere, and this your functions `f1` and `g1` look bit weird, for example this is not valid code:

```
 -logLike<- 0.5*n*log(theta[2])-(1/(2*theta[2]))*sum((x-theta[1])**2)
```

You are trying to assign something to variable called `-logLike`, but you cannot use `-` in variable name.

edit:

Check the documentation of `optimize` on what the function returns:

> Value
>
> A list with components minimum (or maximum) and objective which give
>   the location of the minimum (or maximum) and the value of the function
>   at that point.

So your variable `min` contains two elements although you probably need just the value of the minimum in the next line of your code.

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions. I still got an error for the last equation as: Error in min * newstep : non-numeric argument to binary operator. Should I use "as.numeric" to fix something in my code? Thanks.

Comment: I used edit(gradient.method) but an edit window containing the original code showed up. What do you mean by check the edit? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks again; however, a "min" containing two elements is exactly what I need. Therefore, "newpair" in the last line of the code will also have two elements. If the function "optimize" can only give one element, should I separate "min" into "min[1]" and "min[2]" in order to fix the issue?